# send multiple files data using curl php ( number of files to be sent varies )

Tags: php, file, curl

I need to send multiple files using curl php, but the issue, is the number of files to be sent is varies on the user, hence I have to use some kind of iteration to create array of files to send it using "curl_file_create".

Below is my code for sending just one file. Please feel free to ask any query.

```
        $url = 'http://localhost/target_url';
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Loop over files
        $tmpfile = $_FILES['input_name']['tmp_name'];
        $filename = basename($_FILES['input_name']['name']);
        $fields_string =  array(
            'uploaded_file' => curl_file_create($tmpfile, $_FILES['input_name']['type'], $filename));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response=json_decode($response_json, true);
```

Addition to this question. 
So I have four input( FILE ) fields, and a user can select multiple files for each of those fields. So, once the user has selected the array of files something like this:

```
Array( [x1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => img1.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6F66.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6698
                )

        )

    [x2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => img-2 - Copy.png
                    [1] => img-3.png
                    [2] => img-4.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/png
                    [2] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6F67.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6F77.tmp
                    [2] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6F88.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 165091
                    [1] => 165091
                    [2] => 6698
                )

        )

    [x3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => img-5 - Copy.png
                    [1] => img-6.png
                    [2] => img-6.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/png
                    [2] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6FA8.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6FB9.tmp
                    [2] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6FD9.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 165091
                    [1] => 165091
                    [2] => 6698
                )

        )

)
```

Now I need to know how I can send all these images using curl and since the number of files is not constant, hence there has to be some iteration to be used here. - Solved

Here is the Solution:

```
function uploadfile($tmp_value, $type_value, $imageName){
            $url = 'http://localhost/target_url';
            $ch = curl_init();

            $fields_string =  array(
                'uploaded_file' => curl_file_create($tmp_value, $type_value, $imageName));

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $file_response=json_decode($response_json, true);
            return $response_json;
        } 


foreach ($_FILES as $images_key => $images) {
            foreach ($images['name'] as $imageData_key => $imageName){

                foreach ($images['type'] as $type_key => $type_value) {

                    foreach ($images['tmp_name'] as $tmp_key => $tmp_value) {

                    }

                }

                echo $this->uploadfile($tmp_value, $type_value, $imageName);

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want a good answer you need to share the code of the form used to upload the files.

Comment: Actually the form is too big to understand & that might itself make things hard to understand, but what I can do is explain just the multiple file form part. Let me just post that for you

Comment: You should change `foreach ($images['type'] as $type_key => $type_value)` to `$type_value = $images['type'][$imageData_key]` (and the same with$images['tmp_name'] )

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like that

// calling uploadfile function for each image file in array

```
foreach ($imagesArray as $images_key => $images){
    foreach ($images['name'] as $imageData_key => $imageName){
       $response = uploadfile($imagesArray[$images_key][$imageData_key]['tmp_name'], $imagesArray[$images_key][$imageData_key]['type'], $imageName);
        //do something with $response below
        echo $response;
    }
}
```

//Upload function:

```
function uploadfile($tmpfile, $type, $filename){
    $url = 'http://localhost/target_url';
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Loop over files
    $tmpfile = $_FILES['input_name']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = basename($_FILES['input_name']['name']);
    $fields_string =  array(
        'uploaded_file' => curl_file_create($tmpfile, $type, $filename));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response=json_decode($response_json, true);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Your solution wasn't to the point but it did gave me an idea which solved the issue.  Anyway, I am updating the query with the answer.